# Problems with new Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu

I recently bought a new HP Spectre x360 laptop and installed Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit) for the first time.

I am seeing various bugs. I don't know if the problems are due to:

(a) Hardware problems with the new laptop.

(b) Software issues, i.e. Ubuntu not working with the other programs I have downloaded.

(c) Problems with the resolution I have chosen. Most of the problems seem to be display related. I had issues initially with setting the screen resolution correctly and so I have had to play around a little to get things looking okay with most programs. Screen is 3840 x 2160.

An couple of example of the problems that I am encountering:

When I make a Skype call, I have lots of weird flickering and colour changing etc.

When I use Google Chrome, I sometimes get strange flickering too.

I'm basically trying to isolate my problem before I try to fix it. I know that people have told me to expect Linux to be "buggy" but I don't have a feel of what this means.

Do my problems sound common when trying to use software like Skype and Chrome? Do I need to try a different version of Linux? Do I need to try and fix my resolution issues?

Any advice that might help to point me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: What is/are the graphics chips in that machine, and what drivers are you loading for it?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 520. I don't think I have loaded any drivers. After I received the laptop I just installed Ubuntu.

Comment: check if there are any Ubuntu drivers for this chipset....on the HP page i don't see Ubuntu listed as a compatible OS...if you want to rule out hardware, try running Windows on it to see if behaves differently or not

Comment: Search for "Intel HD Graphics 520 ubuntu", brings up a few posts on AskUbuntu - check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Debian's latest distribution. It should be working fine.
Or look here: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005520.html for workaround on the driver's issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 does not have up to date hardware drivers for x360
I loaded a mainline 4.9 kernel and solved most problems.
Now, 16.04.3 with the HWE stack 4.10 works fine. 
See Joey;

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/ubuntu-16-04-3-lts-released